# Linker error in ipad,iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

Hi am having this error when I am trying to compile my application.i try with replacing the name of buttons still its showing the same?

[image]

Comment: what's ViewCont5? is this view controller or any reference image?

Comment: in your project find some file in Twice that's why you got this error see your error says 6 duplicate symbole

Comment: now i got the other error, i update the image in quest pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow the Steps. hope it helps and if not, please revert.

**1) Open your Project
2) select your project Target 
3) go to the Build Phases Section
4) go to the Compile Sources Tab
5) then search there the files names that xcode are saying duplicated and then remove them.
6) Clean the project and then try Running it.**

Comment: you are may be using the name which is already using by Xcode. try using different name for that property which is getting error and if it the ViewController and please change the name of the View controller also.

Answer (score 0):

Go to x code prefrences [image]

Then go to location and click on small arrow next to "/Deriveddata" and delete derived data

[image]

This should solve it

Comment: did you empty your trash after deleting derived data?

Comment: del app from simulator as well and clean

Comment: sry dnt get it may be has to to do with some btn22 obj or u can remove i386 from build architecture and try running on device